# Access CronWorkflow name for metrics labels

Tags: kustomize, argo-workflows, argo-cron-workflows

I have a CronWorkflow that sends the following metric:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
metadata:
  name: my-cron-wf
spec:
  schedule: "0 * * * *"
  suspend: false
  workflowSpec:
    metrics:
      prometheus:
        - name: wf_exec_duration_gauge
          help: "Duration gauge by workflow name and status"
          labels:
            - key: name
              value: my-cron-wf
            - key: status
              value: "{{workflow.status}}"
          gauge:
            value: "{{workflow.duration}}"
```

I would like to populate the metric's label name with the CronWorkflow name using a variable in order to avoid copying it but I didn't find a variable for it.
I tried to use `{{workflow.name}}` but it equals to the generated workflow name and not to the desired CronWorkflow name.

I use *Kustomize* to manage argo workflows resources so if there is a *kustomize-way* to achieve this it would be great as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argo Workflows [automatically adds](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/pull/4638/files#diff-d6cf0e2c636cfdedcbe6b452c192145c999f8ccbc7016e5a5deffc697e62e0a9R74) the name of the Cron Workflow as a label on the workflow. That label is accessible as a [variable](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/variables/#global).

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
metadata:
  name: my-cron-wf
spec:
  schedule: "0 * * * *"
  suspend: false
  workflowSpec:
    metrics:
      prometheus:
        - name: wf_exec_duration_gauge
          help: "Duration gauge by workflow name and status"
          labels:
            - key: name
              value: "{{workflow.labels.workflows.argoproj.io/cron-workflow}}"
            - key: status
              value: "{{workflow.status}}"
          gauge:
            value: "{{workflow.duration}}"
```

Comment: Thanks @crenshaw-dev but I don't want to hardcode the name neither in labels nor in the metric itself as I want to make it reusable Kustomize component that will be added to every cron workflow. Currently I have it hardcoded and it requires me to add the same metric to each and every cron workflow in my deployment.

Comment: @Gabip updated with a better solution. :-)

Comment: really neat solution! Thank you!